EXEC a SSIS package containing a variable to use in a SQL Task
I am trying to execute a SSIS package with a duration of time down to the SSIS package
USE SSISDB;

DECLARE @execution_id BIGINT
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution] 
    @package_name=N'PackageName.dtsx',
    @folder_name=N'Projects',
    @project_name=N'ProjectName',
    @use32bitruntime=False,
    @reference_id=Null,
    @execution_id=@execution_id OUTPUT

--SELECT @execution_id

DECLARE @var0 smallint = 1
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] 
      @execution_id,
      @object_type=50,
      @parameter_name=N'LOGGING_LEVEL',
      @parameter_value=@var0

/*  Attempt to use a variable to execute in the SQL as a parameter */
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] 
      @execution_id,
      @object_type=20,
      @parameter_name=N'RunDuration', 
      @parameter_value=10080 /*1 week*/

EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution] @execution_id
GO

I have a variable in the SSIS package called User::Duration
I have a SQL Task that I want to use this input in a SQL command:
SQL Statement
Parameter mapping
DECLARE @DURATION SMALLINT;  /* I think the variable would go here as an "= ?" but I am not sure of the rest 
/* Need to research how to make @Duration a variable of the SSIS package. */

DECLARE @TIME DATETIME = DATEADD(mi,-@DURATION,GETDATE()); 

Once I set "@TIME" the rest of the scripting does stuff.
I tried to just get the variable to run but it does not seem to set the @DURATION and the SSIS package fails.
I am hoping to get a scheduled task > correct SSIS execution scripting (hopefully I am close) > the SSIS package Variable to contain the inputed number > the inputed number be able to use in a SQL task, sql command.

Instead of a variable, use a package parameter: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/integration-services-ssis-package-and-project-parameters?view=sql-server-ver16

Create a package parameter:

Change the sql task to use the parameter instead of the variable:


Then your sql above sql to run the package and set the parameter should work.

Thank you for your answer.
When I try to add the parameters I do not have the add, move or delete parameters.
When I click in the Package Explorer I cannot add the parameters.
Msg 27106, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SSISDB.catalog.set_object_parameter_value, Line 163 [Batch Start Line 0]
Cannot find the parameter 'RunDuration' because it does not exist.

@MRSKINNMAN you need to change your project type - right click the project name in the explorer > Convert to project deployment model.  However, this has implications for where you deploy your project and how it is executed.  You can learn more about there here: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4309/integration-services-ssis-convert-from-package-deployment-model-to-project-deployment-model/
